# Typescript custom list of lists number

Tags: arrays, angular, list, typescript, structure

I look for the possibility to declare and fill a typescript list of lists.

The list should be built up like:

```
List<CustomList<>,number>
```

Normal I would create a normal list like:

```
someList: { text: any, value: any }[] = [];
```

Now I need something similar like this:

```
List<someList, id: number>
```

Has someone the same issue or any idea?

Regards

Comment: What is the issue here?

Comment: I dont know how could i declare such a list

Comment: You mean how to type a list of lists?

Comment: the list item has a custom list and a number?

Comment: correctly special is it has to be a custom list of custom lists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do something like this :

```
list: {id: number, list: {
  id: number,
  item1: string,
  // etc.
}[]}[] = [];
```

Answer (score 3):

Most possibly you need an array of typed arrays, as follows:

```js
let myVar: Array<Array<SomeType>> = [];
```

Or if you have a `CustomList`, then you can:

```js
let myVar: CustomList<CustomList<number>> = new CustomList();
```

For example